# Factory functions prototype

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

Learning constructors I came with this question:

> *Why not to use just normal functions returning an object instead of constructors?*

Reading a bit, I found about factory functions (ff). The differences with constructors are:

- The use of `this` that replaces the object literal `{ }`,
- The use of `new` replacing the `return` of the object.

But that's not enough simplification I believe, it's just a bit tidier, but not much.

Take this example:

```
function box(x,y,z){
return { 
        x:x , y:y , z:z , 
        volume: function (){return x*y*z} 
        }
   }
```

We can easily write a constructor with same function.

Now, I know one of the differences might be the prototype. So here is my question:

- What are the key differences between ff and constructors? Is the prototype a difference between factory functions and constructors?

Comment: A key difference is that the constructor also sets up the prototype chain while the factory function doesn't.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Does this imply we can't access Object methods like hasOwnProperty etc. ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. And you can set the prototype chain with a factory, when you'd return a chained object: `return Object.create(Box.prototype, {...});` (providing you've `Box` function defined.).

Comment: @Teemu but if is doesn't how isn't that a chain? Anyways I think I get that ff do not create a prototype although we can add it. Then it's just one declaration shorter...

Comment: A factory function doesn't have to use object literal syntax. The (only) key difference between constructors and factory functions is that the latter are not called with `new`. It doesn't matter how they construct the object that they return.

Comment: @misternobody When you're creating an object with object literal, the used prototype is `Object.prototype`, you can change that prototype by creating an instance with `Object.create`, and choose any object as the prototype, or even `null`, when the newly-created object doesn't inherit any properties from its prototype. Object factory is a bit more flexible than a constructor, since you can use `this` in a factory function to refer some other object than the object to be created. This is just a consequence of not using `new` when creating the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype object that is created together with the function is indeed making the difference. When you call the function with `new`, the `this` object will get that prototype object as its prototype. So the prototype chain for that new object is one step longer than what you get with the factory function.

### instanceof

The language offers the `instanceof` operator and the `constructor` property, which are useful when you use constructors, as they give information about the instance's constructor. In the case of an object literal (as used in your `box` function), *that* determines that the constructor is `Object` and not `box`.

To bring the two versions of the functions a bit closer together, so that only the essential differences are highlighted, you could write them as follows:

```
function box(x,y,z) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.x = x;
    obj.y = y;
    obj.z = z;
    // Better reference the properties here, ...in case they are changed:
    obj.volume = function () { return obj.x * obj.y * obj.z } 
    return obj;
}
```

The constructor could look like this:

```
function Box(x,y,z) {
    // `this` is already initialised as a new object with a specific prototype
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.volume = function () { return this.x * this.y * this.z }
    // `this` is returned by default, so no `return` is needed
}
```

Notice the difference in the prototype chains (run the snippet) and the usefulness of `instanceof`:

```js
function box(x,y,z) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.x = x;
    obj.y = y;
    obj.z = z;
    obj.volume = function () { return obj.x * obj.y * obj.z } 
    return obj;
}

function Box(x,y,z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.volume = function () { return this.x * this.y * this.z }
}

let a = box(1,2,3);
let b = new Box(1,2,3);

// Print prototype chains
console.log("a-->" + Object.getPrototypeOf(a).constructor.name);

let protB = Object.getPrototypeOf(b);
console.log("b-->" + protB.constructor.name + "-->" + 
                     Object.getPrototypeOf(protB).constructor.name);

// Print use of `instanceOf`
console.log("a instanceof box?", a instanceof box);
console.log("b instanceof Box?", b instanceof Box);
```

### Methods

So far I ignored the fact that the `volume` function could be reused instead of defined separately for each instance. You can in both cases define the `volume` function as a (more) global function. Note that you now could use the `this` keyword, since normally you would call `volume` as `instance.volume()`:

```
function volume { return this.x * this.y * this.z }

function box(x,y,z) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.x = x;
    obj.y = y;
    obj.z = z;
    obj.volume = volume; 
    return obj;
}
```

Still, you have the explicit `obj.volume = volume` assignment. In the constructor pattern, you don't need to create that instance property. It is enough the define the method on the prototype object:

```
function Box(x,y,z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    // No need here to define `volume`
}

Box.prototype.volume = function { return this.x * this.y * this.z };
```

So, actually you only have one reference to the method.

### Class syntax

Finally, there is the `class` syntax, which is an alternative to use constructors:

```
class Box(x,y,z) {
    constructor(x,y,z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    volume() {
        return this.x * this.y * this.z;
    }
}
```

In this syntax `volume` is also defined on the prototype, not on the instance.

### Downsides to using constructors

So far, the comparison was favourable to using constructors (in my opinion).

But:

- The use of the `this` object can be avoided completely by using factory functions. Using `this` can be confusing (as the many questions on that topic on Stack Overflow demonstrate). Some coders feel this is good reason to abandon constructors.
- Creating longer prototype chains can [impact performance negatively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Performance) and sometimes make simple tasks look complicated. For the above example there is no such problem, but the typical examples for using Object Oriented Programming, where you have a `Being` from which `Animal` is derived, from which `Mammal` is derived, from which ...etc, etc, can get confusing. A flat data structure can then feel like a relief.

Comment: "*Creating longer prototype chains can impact performance negatively*" - really? Engines typically optimise the lookup away.

Comment: @Bergi, I suppose engines do a good job in optimising. But still, could you have a look at [this JS bench](https://jsben.ch/ZyHsV). Unless I made a mistake, I think this shows that iteration over properties with `in` is slightly slower when the prototype chain is longer.

Comment: I see, I was thinking of calling the prototype methods. Enumerating them is not a that common use case.

Comment: Man thanks for this, I'll study hard to get better at js

Answer (score 0):

YES, Prototype is a difference between the so called factory functions and constructors.

In the sample code that you had given, you won't be able to access the prototype of `box`, even if that is added. When you call a function with `new` keyword, the first job that it would do internally is to create an object and create its prototype chain based on the references that you given via `box.prototype` and after setting that up the process will return the object created. But here in your code, the access has been restricted to the object that you are returning and it will override the return of the originally created object.